# Does capybara replace selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

When using capybara for testing, do you still need the likes of selenium?

What are the advantages of either solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara uses Selenium as one of its drivers. By default, Capybara uses the Rack::Test driver instead of controlling an actual browser with Selenium, but when you run Javascript tests, the Selenium driver is the default.

The [project's README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) gives a good overview of how the pieces fit together.